# Graph LaTeX help

Tags: graphics

Hello I am trying to create the following model in LaTeX and was wondering if anyone could help me. I am fairly new to LaTeX, so I need some help.

[image]

Comment: What are those scribbles for?

Comment: Have you seen [TikZ](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf)? It's a complex drawing library, but learning how to use it will save you many troubles and allow you to create beautiful pictures!

Comment: If you google "tikz lines with ticks" and search for images, you get exactly what you're looking for. If that's not what you're looking for, then you should make sure that is accurately explained in your question.

Answer (score 6):

Of course, we're all very glad to help! We're even gladder to help when you show us what you've tried or indicate where exactly you're having trouble. If you're completely new to using `LaTeX` and writing or making pictures in it, take a look at the [Help center](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help) about how to get the most out of this forum. Here's an example that should give you what you want (judging from your picture) and get you well on your way. Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[<->] (0,0)--(4,0);
\foreach \x in {1,...,7}{
  \fill[black] (\x/2,0) circle (.05);
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And here's the result:

[image]

I've used `TikZ`, which a very powerful tool to make all sorts of different pictures, and there's quite a lot of (free) resources out there to help you get started with it.

Comment: You could do it as a one-liner: `\tikz\draw[<->] (0,0) foreach \x in {1,...,7}{ -- (\x/2,0) node[draw,fill,circle,inner sep=1pt] {} } -- (4,0);`